# Can't connect to local SQL Server DB when I have no internet connection

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, localhost, localdb

If I have an internet connection my local website connects to my local database just fine.  I am wanting to work remotely without internet connection... How can I set things up so that I can connect?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 and IIS7

Comment: Anybody?  Trying to work from the train this week... Not going to work so great if I have to have an internet connection to make it work... Any ideas are welcome.